# Получить на вход определенное число переменных, заданное пользователем

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, ввод

Возникла проблема с получением данных. Пользователь задает число, и вводит даные в это число переменных. Понимаю, что проблема со списком, но не знаю как исправить. Выдает следующую ошибку:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range.

```
n = int(input("Сколько переменных с данными вам необходимо?"))
a = [2]
for i in range(0, n):
    a[i] = int(input(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, если ее перечитать, сообщает о том, что вышли за пределы списка.

У Вас длина списка `a = [2]` равна одному элементу. После того, как Вы подключаете цикл, то для `i = 1` (второй элемент по счету) вы уже выходите за пределы списка. В этом случае лучше использовать метод списка `append()`, который добавляет к списку еще один элемент.

```
n = int(input("Сколько переменных с данными вам необходимо?"))
a = []
for i in range(0, n):
    a.append(int(input("Введите число")))
```